# MySQL INSERT record using SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `tblcity` and `tblcityx`:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tblcity`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcity` (
  `pkcityid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cityname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `fkstateid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkcityid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblcityx`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcityx` (
 `pkcityid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `cityname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `fkstateid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pkcityid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I am trying to add a new record in `tblcity` from `tblcityx`. Currently, I have tried:

```
$cityid = 10; // could be any city id
INSERT INTO `tblcity` (SELECT * FROM `tblcityx` WHERE pkcityid = '$cityid')
```

Both tables have same number of fields and `pkcityid` is auto-incremented.

It adds a new DUPLICATE record in `tblcity` as it has already a city with `pkcityid=10`, so after running the above query there are two records with `pkcityid=10`.

Isn't there a way that even if the `tblcity` already has a city with that `pkcityid`, it should always add a NEW record?

Might be straight forward for an expert but I'm unable to find a way through.

Comment: `pkcityid` should be primary key, or at least have a `UNIQUE` constraint. Can you change that? Otherwise, there is no simple way to do that with a simple SQL statement (you could still do what you want with a convoluted stored procedure, or with an external script).

Comment: `pkcityid` is primary key in both tables but the problem stands still.

Comment: Then how comes it "adds a new DUPLICATE record in `tblcity`"?! Or did you mean it *raises a DUPLICATE error* ?

Comment: a DUPLICATE record has been inserted that was may be due `UNIQUE` constraint was not been set.

Comment: You are right it should have prompted me with a _DUPLICATE_ error.

Comment: Could you post your full table structure, as reported by `SHOW CREATE TABLE the_table` ?

Comment: I have edited my question and added table structures. Pardon me for being late.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure there is a PK on `pkcityid`. There is one, and I can't think of any way to disable the PK unique constraint checks, so I can only assume the table is broken. Try re-creating the tables.

Comment: You might be right, let me re-create both tables and see if it resolves it.

Comment: after I re-created the tables and ran the query, it prompted me with _DUPLICATE_ for entry, can't we anyhow skip `pkcityid` check as `tblcity` has record with the same `pkcityid`, to be able to INSERT a NEW record?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! Let me elaborate an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make MySQL generate a new auto-incremented value by providing `NULL` as value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column:

```
INSERT INTO target_table
    SELECT NULL, cityname, fkstateid
    FROM source_table
    WHERE pkcityid = @your_id;
```

*note: the `AUTO_INCREMENT`column **must** be defined as `NOT NULL` for this to work*

You probably want to check for the existence of @your_id in the target table. Something along the lines of:

```
if (@your_id does not exist in target_table) {
    INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * ...
} else {
    INSERT INTO target_table SELECT NULL, cityname ...
}
```

Comment: Check the [Reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Works a treat! Exactly, what I wanted. Can't believe it was that simple at the end. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if pkcityid is your primary key. Primary Keys can only exist once in a table. You may add a timestamp field that is automatically set to the current timestamp when inserting a row and add that to the key. then you have a combined key of id and timestamp, which will be unique when inserting a new record.

Comment: you mean in `tblcityx` `pkcityid` should not be a primary key? Unfortunately, both tables have the same structure.

Comment: The field can be a primary key, but you will need another field which also is a primary key. You can not have identical records if there is a primary key on any field. If you add a timestamp field that indicates when the record was added and make that a primary key as well it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not add fields in the tables. In that case I guess, you are right, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example. 
you can use the column name which you wants

Like this

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

check this example you will get to know
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

if both table having the same stucture than you can use the alias for remove the naming ambiguity.

here is example "how to give alias name"

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Actually, both tables have the same structure so this query is not solving my case, I have already tried this!

Comment: if both table having the same stucture than you can use the alias for remove the naming ambiguity.

here is example "how to give alias name"

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: we can not use aliases for `INSERT` queries, and for the `SELECT` query I introduce an alias, it will still get that `pkcityid` e.g, 10.